# C# dynamically delete checkboxes

Tags: c#, winforms, dynamic, checkbox

I'm trying to delete checked checkboxes from a groupbox by pressing a button. After this I want the rest checkboxes to be in an order.

Here is my code for deleting checkboxes:

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
       for(int i=0; i<=number_ch; i++)
       {
            foreach(Control c in groupBox2.Controls)
            {
                if(c.GetType().Name=="CheckBox")
                {
                    if(((CheckBox)c).Checked==true)
                    {
                        groupBox2.Controls.Remove(c);
                        number_ch--;
                    }
                }
            }
       }
 }
```

It works good but how do I put the rest in order?

Comment: What is the platform?

Comment: @user3616435 Dude, That's fine. Winforms or wpf or asp.net?

Comment: oh, i' m sorry...Winforms

Comment: Ok, you said rest of the controls to be in order, but what order? We don't know what order it is currently in? Are you aware of flowlayoutpanel? It will arrange the controls automatically.

Comment: the rest checkboxes are at random order and i want to be one under the other one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not delete the controls, make them `Visible=false` !

Comment: You should mention that controls which are `Visible=false` on serverside are not rendered at all on client-side. This is the best apporach if the number of "dynamic" controls is fix.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: you're right, it seems to be winforms but i somehow assumed webforms.